# How to validate response XML with request XML in SOAP UI Pro

Tags: xml, groovy, soapui, restful-authentication, functional-testing

Our project demands thorough REST API testing. So we are using SOAP-UI Pro for REST web-service testing.

I want to test the following scenario:

Storing an 'XML' file and make sure that to fetch the same 'XML' file.

Need to validate 'request-XML' with response 'XML' where some 'XML-tags' are dynamic for example:

Request 'XML' is:

```
<c:field xmlns:c="http://iddn.icis.com/ns/core">  
   <c:id>http://iddn.icis.com/fields/low</c:id>   
   <c:version>1</c:version>   
   <c:created-on>2012-08-13T11:01:39Z</c:created-on>   
   <c:type>field</c:type>
   <c:name>low</c:name>
   <c:value type="integer" /> 
   <c:description xml:lang="en">
      <c:name>low</c:name>
   </c:description>
</c:field>
```

While fetching we need to verify that we are getting the above 'XML' back.

I tried to validate by using "assert content" but its failing as the `<c:created-on>2012-08-13T11:01:39Z</c:created-on>` value is  changing every time we are storing it.

how to handle dynamic response 'XML' tags in 'SOAP-UI' testing ?

Note : I am new to Groovy, x-path and X-query as well as SOAP UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to define an assertion test script with the next script, maybe this will help you

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( "Request#Request" );
def holder2 = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("Responses#ResponseAsXml")

def stringList=[]
def stringList2=[]

for( node in holder['//name] )
{  
  stringList =stringList+node 
}


for( node2 in holder2['//name'] )
{ 
  stringList2 =stringList2+node2 
    if (node2 in stringList ) assert true
    else assert null
}


log.info "Request>" + stringList
log.info "result>"+ stringList2
```